# Include local image in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I'm trying to include a picture from my ubuntu machine into a gvisTable.

The path is specified as

```
<img src="google_logo.jpg"/>
```

And the folder structure looks like this:

```
+---/srv/shiny-server
|   +---shinyApp
|       +---server.R
|       +---ui.R
|           +---wwww
|               +---google_logo.jpg
```

Pictures with an url do work, I played around with different placements of google_logo.jpg and the permission of google_logo.jpg, but I can't make it work.

In my css file I can access local images in the same directory with `url("image.png")`

Any suggestions?